1950's Movie - Scotland Yard after a murderer, UK
I guess this is a remote question being that movie was a B just to fill in a bit of time. 
I definitely saw this in the early 50's and was of course in black and white. A murder took place in London, Scotland Yard was called in. 
The only clue they had was that the murderer had left his newspaper in the car he used. It had a number, example only is this... "19 V" .. was similar to clue. Was of course to aid its delivery. Hence they knew he/she lived at a certain number, in a place starting with one letter . Well, against all odds he was caught and hanged. 
I have bought all Edgar Wallace and all Scotland Yard series out on DVD but to no avail. 

Sounds a bit like this scene from The Long Arm, but it's not a perfect fit. Do you perhaps remember the actors or what they looked like?

Walt, thanks very much indeed, that sure seems like the movie I was after. I am 72 now and was possibly only 12/13/14 yrs old when saw this movie, hence you have done very well indeed,as it seems what I thought I remembered was some way off. It may have been the 2nd film under Rob Roy, the Richard Todd version. Thanks again, Don
